# How to get the affected table name from DataSet, SQLDataAdapter or SQLCommandBuilder?

Tags: ado.net

I am doing a simple connect, fill, update operation using an SQLConnector, an SQLCommandBuilder and a DataSet.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connectionString = "server=scratch;database=scratch;user=scratch;password=scratch";
        theConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

        theDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM scratch", theConnection);
        theCommandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(theDataAdapter);

        theDataSet = new DataSet();
        theDataAdapter.Fill(theDataSet);

        dataGridView1.DataSource = theDataSet.Tables[0];
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        theDataAdapter.Update(theDataSet.Tables[0]);
    }
```

I want to log the name of the table, but the TableName of the tables in the dataset is always 'Table'. The command builder uses the table name to create the Update, Insert and Delete commands but I can't find a method or property of SQLCommandBulider or DBCommandBuilder that returns it.

For maintainablilty's sake I'd prefer to keep the changes in the second event. So I don't want to require anything additional when setting up the DataAdatpter or DataSet (such as explicitly setting the DataTables' TableNames). Parsing the output of GetUpdateCommand() also just sounds kludgy.

What is the neat, correct way to get the name of the affected database table at update time?

... or am I just being too picky about what I don't want to do?

Comment: Just a tip, you really need to dispose of your database objects. Wrap your theConnection, theDataAdapter and theCommandBuilder each in their own using() {} clauses.

Comment: Yeah ... I copied the constructor stuff into the first event to keep the excerpt simple and didn't copy any of the disposal ... the actual code isn't that messy (nor does it have such odd variable names)